# Invalid column name en un Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, trigger

Quería crear un trigger el cual eliminara un cliente si este no tiene teléfono. Lo he intentado y en el IF, el 'telefonoCliente is NULL', me da error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSERTAR_CLIENTE
ON Cliente
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Cliente (idCliente, nomCliente, dirCliente, idpais, telefonoCliente)
select telefonoCliente 
from inserted
IF (telefonoCliente is NULL)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END;
```

Comment: pregunta, no es más fácil poner `NOT NULL` el campo, en vez de usar el trigger?

Comment: Si quitas la sentencia `if` completa, el trigger, tal como está escrito, va a duplicar toda la información que se inserte a la tabla. Realmente no sé que buscas lograr, pero, si es lo que creo, creo que es mejor que pongas el atributo `not null` a la columna teléfono. Si no es eso, vendría bien que expliques en la pregunta qué es lo que estás intentando lograr.

Comment: Me da la impresión que tienes una confusión respecto a lo que hace un trigger, por que el código y lo que buscas no tiene mucho sentido. Podrías invalidar la inserción, pero no tiene sentido que el trigger elimine lo que se acaba de insertar.